# laying out images in UIScrollView automatically

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, uiscrollview

i have a list of images retrieved from xml i want to populate them to a uiscrollview in an order such that it will look like this.

### 1 2 3

### 4 5 6

### 7 8 9

### 10

if there is only 10 images it will just stop here.

right now my current code is this

```
for (int i = 3; i<[appDelegate.ZensaiALLitems count]-1; i++) {
        UIButton *zenbutton2 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        Items *ZensaiPLUitems = [appDelegate.ZensaiALLitems objectAtIndex:i];
        NSURL *ZensaiimageSmallURL = [NSURL URLWithString:ZensaiPLUitems.ZensaiimageSmallURL];
        NSLog(@"FVGFVEFV :%@", ZensaiPLUitems.ZensaiimageSmallURL);
        NSData *simageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ZensaiimageSmallURL];
        UIImage *itemSmallimage = [UIImage imageWithData:simageData];
        [zenbutton2 setImage:itemSmallimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        zenbutton2.frame=CGRectMake( (i*110+i*110)-660 , 300, 200, 250);
        [zenbutton2 addTarget:self action:@selector(ShowNextZensaiPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [scrollView addSubview:zenbutton2];
}
```

notice the CGRectMake , i have to manually assign fixed values to position them.
Is there any way to populate them out without manually assigning.
for e.g the images will automatically go down a position once the first row has 3 images and subsequently for the rest.

Comment: If you want to avoid reinventing this wheel, have you looked at [`AQGridView`](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView)?

Comment: @Deepak +1 for AQGridView. But AQGridView is not working properly I had tried that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you are saying, you should be able to write a simple block of code that assigns a position based on the image number.

Something like this (where i is the image number, starting from 0):

```
- (CGPoint)getImageOrigin:(NSInteger)imageNumber {

    CGFloat leftInset = 30;
    CGFloat xOffsetBetweenOrigins = 80;
    CGFloat topInset = 20;
    CGFloat yOffsetBetweenOrigins = 80;

    int numPerRow = 3;

    CGFloat x = leftInset + (xOffsetBetweenOrigins * (imageNumber % numPerRow));
    CGFloat y = topInset + (yOffsetBetweenOrigins * floorf(imageNumber / numPerRow));

    CGPoint imageOrigin = CGPointMake(x, y);

    return imageOrigin;

}
```

The origin being calculated here is the upper left corner of each image.

To calculate the x value, I start with the minimum distance from the left side of the screen (leftInset). Then, I add the distance from the left side of one image to the next image, multiplied by the column (`imageNumber % numPerRow`).

Y is calculated in a similar fashion, but to calculate the row, I use the `imageNumber / numPerRow` rounded down.

Edit:

You asked me to explain further, so I'll see what I can do.

OK, so I want to be able to input the image number (starting at 0) into my function, and I want the origin (upper left corner point) back.

`leftInset` is the distance between the left edge of the view, and the left edge of the first image.

`xOffsetBetweenOrigins` is the distance from the left edge of one image to the left edge of the next image on the same row. So, if I set it to 80 and my image is 50px wide, there will be a 30px gap between two images in the same row.

`topInset` is like left inset. It is the distance from the top edge of the view to the top edge of the images in the top row.

`yOffsetBetweenOrigins` is the distance from the top edge of an image to the top edge of the image below it. If I set this to 80, and my image is 50px tall, then there will be a 30px vertical gap between rows.

`numPerRow` is straightforward. It is just the number of images per row.

To calculate the x value of the upper left corner of the image, I always start with the leftInset, because it is constant. If I am on the first image of a row, that will be the entire x value. If I am on the second image of the row, I need to add `xOffsetBetweenOrigins` once, and if I am on the third, I need to add it twice.

To do this, I use the modulus (%) operator. It gives me the remainder of a division operation, so when I say imageNumber % numPerRow, I am asking for the remainder of imageNumber/numPerRow.
If I am on the first image (imageNumber = 0), then 3 goes into 0 no times, and the remainder is 0. If I am on the second image (imageNumber = 1), then I have 1/3. 3 goes into 1 0 times, but the remainder is 1, so I get xOffsetBetweenOrigins*1.

For the y value, I do something similar, but instead of taking the modulus, I simply divide imageNumber/numPerRow and round down. Doing this, I will get 0 for 0, 1, and 2. I will get 1 for 3, 4, and 5.

Edit:

It occurred to me that you might actually have been asking how to use this method. In your code, you would say something like

```
CGRect newFrame = zenbutton2.frame;
newFrame.origin = [self getImageOrigin:i];
zenbutton2.frame = newFrame;
```

Another Edit:

Maybe you could try this?

```
CGPoint origin = [self getImageOrigin:i];
zenbutton2.frame = CGRectMake(origin.x, origin.y, width, height);
```

If that doesn't work, throw in

```
NSLog("Origin Values: %f,%f", origin.x, origin.y);
```

to make sure that you are actually getting something back from `getImageOrigin`.

Comment: can you give me a more detailed explaination? i don't really get it , sorry bout that!

Comment: Sure thing! Is there a specific part you want to know more about?

Comment: thanks! i'm clear of it now. but how do i implement this function with my method? i'm not really familiar with CGPoint. thanks for the help.

Comment: If you say frame.origin, that accepts a CGPoint. As far as I am aware, a CGRect is just a struct consisting of a CGPoint (origin), and a CGSize (size).

Comment: when i assign the frame.origin to the UIButton , it tells me that the "expression is not assignable" is it because button.frame cannot be assigned?

Comment: now my code looks like this :

//image is init with url 
UIImage *itemSmallimage = [UIImage imageWithData:simageData];

//init with image
[zenbutton2 setImage:itemSmallimage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//declare the frame like what you said
CGRect newFrame = zenbutton2.frame;
newFrame.origin = [self getImageOrigin:i];
zenbutton2.frame = newFrame;

[scrollView addSubview:zenbutton2];

and now my scrollview doesnt display the images, whats wrong?
**copy paste into notepad for easier viewing**

Comment: i wrote zenbutton2.frame = CGRectMake (x,y,width,height) and it displays images .
but when i used your method newFrame.origin = [self getImageOrigin:i] it doesn't display any images

Comment: hey kat , i solved the problem already! problem lies with my UIButton is set to customType thats why it doesn't display the images as its supposed to be. Anyway your solution did help me out alot , really appreciate it! thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to wrap your loop in another loop, to get what I'm going to call a 2D loop:

```
for (int row = 0; row < num_rows; row++) {
   for (int col = 0; col < num_cols; col++) {
        // code before
        zenButton2.frame = CGRectMake(origin x dependent on col,
                                      origin y dependent on row,
                                      width,
                                      height);
        // code after
   }
}
```

Where the `x` and `y` of the `CGRectMake()` are multiples of the width and height of your image times the row and column respectively. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: when i use the method Items *ZensaiPLUitems = [appDelegate.ZensaiALLitems objectAtIndex:i];
all my images are the same