# UIButton with CGRect doesn't appear in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uibutton, cgrect

```
- (CGPoint)getImageOrigin:(NSInteger)imageNumber {
CGFloat leftInset = 40;
CGFloat xOffsetBetweenOrigins = 100;
CGFloat topInset = 40;
CGFloat yOffsetBetweenOrigins = 100;
int numPerRow = 3;
CGFloat x = leftInset + (xOffsetBetweenOrigins * (imageNumber % numPerRow));
CGFloat y = topInset + (yOffsetBetweenOrigins * floorf(imageNumber / numPerRow));
CGPoint imageOrigin = CGPointMake(x, y);
return imageOrigin;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{
UIButton *zenbutton2 =[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect newFrame = zenbutton2.frame;
newFrame.origin = [self **getImageOrigin**:i];
zenbutton2.frame = newFrame;
[scrollView addSubview:zenbutton2];  
}
```

followed the method here : [laying out images in UIScrollView automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488169/laying-out-images-in-uiscrollview-automatically)

but my UIButton doesnt appear in my scrollView , any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UIButton is of UIButtonTypeCustom. So you should set a background color or Image to see the button.

```
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or

```
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]
```

Try this.

Comment: oh ya thanks! been doing for 34hours non-stop , couldn't spot such silly mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set scrollVew's content size after adding button's.

Comment: yeah i already did ,[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(600,800))];