# Displaying UIImageViews with label/buttons in them

Tags: objective-c, layout, uiimageview

I need to display images with buttons in them. The number of images displayed depends on how many objects there in the array. I'm able to get a layout of my images with the help of - 
[laying out images in UIScrollView automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488169/laying-out-images-in-uiscrollview-automatically)

However, I need to have a label and buttons in my images.

```
e.g
 _____   _____
|a  oo| |a  oo|
|     | |     |
|     | |     |
|_____| |_____|
 _____   _____
|a  oo| |a  oo|
|     | |     |
|     | |     |
|_____| |_____|
 _____   _____
|a  oo| |a  oo|
|     | |     |
|     | |     |
|_____| |_____|

(a=label, o=buttons)
```

Will adding another UIView with my image+button layout design to my main view work? If so, how do I go about this? Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 1):

if you add a button inside a UIImageView as subview, the button wont respond to touch events. So use UIView instead of imageview to add buttons and labels. You can give background image for that view using

```
myView.backgroundColor= [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"]];
```

Comment: Thanks that works too. I set UIImageView's userInteractionEnabled to YES and it works fine. My real problem is positioning the buttons and label.

Comment: it seems to be easy since the position of the labels and buttons in all the imageview are same. you can hard code the positions.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the subview to the images:

> [anImage
>   addSubview:someButtonOrLabelView];

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it gets complex because I layout the images via a separate method, in which the position varies for each image. Wouldn't the buttons go out of place?

Comment: They will be placed relative to the imageView you add them to. Tell me how you want the images to appear? (where and relative to what?)